Existence of a triangle with sides $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$ and area less than $\frac{\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C}{8}$.

Question:
Given angles $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A + B + C < 180^\circ$. Show that there exists a triangle with sides $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$ and that it's  area is less than  $\frac{\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C}{8}$.

Attempted Solution:
Yesterday I encountered this problem while doing some trigonometry questions it was the last 16th question in the worksheet. Since then I am thinking about this, it is a quite interesting but also a challenging and thought provoking one.
To prove that $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$ can form the sides of a triangle, I checked the following triangle inequalites:

$\sin A + \sin B > \sin C$

$\sin B + \sin C > \sin A$

$\sin C + \sin A > \sin B$


Since $A + B + C < 180^\circ$, all angles $A$, $B$, and $C$ are less than $180^\circ$, implying that each of these angles is acute. For acute angles, the sine function is positive. Therefore, $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$ are all positive.
I believe the triangle inequalities hold because $\sin(x)$ is a smooth, continuous function over $(0, \pi)$. Since $A + B < 180^\circ - C$, angles $A$ and $B$ are sufficient to ensure $\sin A + \sin B > \sin C$, and similarly for the other inequalities. Thus, $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$ satisfy the conditions to form a valid triangle.
Let $s = \frac{\sin A + \sin B + \sin C}{2}$ be the semi-perimeter of the triangle formed by sides $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$. The area $\Delta$ can be expressed using Heron's formula:
$\Delta = \sqrt{s(s - \sin A)(s - \sin B)(s - \sin C)}$
Alternatively, if we consider the formula $\Delta = \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot b \cdot \sin(\theta)$ where $a = \sin A$, $b = \sin B$, and $\theta$ is the included angle, we could try bounding the area in a more straightforward way.
I am trying to show that:
$\Delta < \frac{\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C}{8}$
By exploring a bound, I considered:
$\Delta \leq \frac{1}{4} \cdot \sin A \cdot \sin B$
where the maximum area occurs when $\theta = 90^\circ$. However, I feel this approach is incomplete because I cannot see a direct way to use the given upper bound in terms of the sum of the sides $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$.
Stuck Point :
I’m currently stuck on rigorously proving that the expression $\frac{1}{4} \cdot \sin A \cdot \sin B$ or any similar expression will be strictly less than $\frac{\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C}{8}$.
Could there be a more elegant approach or symmetry argument that simplifies the problem? Any hints or suggestions to proceed further would be greatly appreciated.


Why should all angles be acute? Consider $10^\circ, 10^\circ, 100^\circ$.

Ok i got its not necessary

Do you also see that $\sin(10^\circ) + \sin(10^\circ) < \sin(100^\circ)$?

@Vasili No, the statement requires existence for all values (IE For all given A, B, C, show that there exists ...). It is not asking to prove existence of an example (Show that there exists some A, B, C such that ...)

The claim as it is stated is false. If $A=B=10^{\circ}, C=90^{\circ}$ then $\sin A + \sin B < \sin C$. Thus there is no triangle with sides $\sin 10^{\circ}, \sin 10^{\circ}, \sin 90^{\circ}.$ Probably there are more assumptions: let's say $A+B>C$ and so on. Could you revise if the question is properly written? Or could you give some more details?

It is correctly written it came in a math competition
